# How to display text in 2 color using script?

Tags: javascript, php, internet-explorer, text

How to display text in 2 color using script ?

first show text color #ccc 1 sec and then show text color #000 1 sec and then show text color #ccc 1 sec (loop)

Comment: Do you mean Java or JavaScript?

Answer (score 2):

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/spU2h/1/)

you can achieve that with setInvterval

```
function changeColor()
{
    if(document.getElementById('mySpan').style.color == "rgb(0, 0, 0)" || document.getElementById('mySpan').style.color == "#000000")
    document.getElementById('mySpan').style.color = "#ccc";
    else
    document.getElementById('mySpan').style.color = "#000";
}

setInterval("changeColor()",1000);
```

and html:

```
<span id='mySpan'>some text</span>
```

Comment: try alerting `document.getElementById('mySpan').style.color` in ie7 and in second alert whatever is alerted put that instead of `#000000`
i don't have ie7 hence can't test it myself.

Comment: Why do you use ie7? Try another browser!